# Raising Errors and If-Else Statements nested in try-except blocks

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

so I am working on a personal project where I simply recreate the game mechanics of Battleship (the board game). The main issue I have encountered so far since beginning of this project is the system for raising errors; I would move onto another part of the project but I am so fixated on this.

I have tried many iterations of how this could possibly work given my limited knowledge of programming but none of it is working. This is what I've got so far:

```
def prompting():
    while True:
        try:
            x = input('Please select the coordinate at which you would like to begin placing the aircraft carrier (5-units):')
            break
        except ValueError:
            check_validity(x)
            if x is False:
                print('Coordinates are indicated by letter A - J on the vertical axis and 1 - 10 on the horizontal axis. Please use the values to indicate a valid coordinate:')
            
prompting()
```

For my project, I am using a 10 x 10 matrix to act as the board and I have a dictionary that associates the indexed positions of each element of the matrix (the keys) with an coordinate identifiers that include letter A-J on the vertical axis and 1-10 on the horizontal axis (ex A1, A2, A3...A10 - J1...J10. I have a function that checks the validity of the coordinate that the user input:

```
def check_validity(coordinate):   
    keys = list(coordinates_dict.keys()) 
    for i in keys:
        if coordinate in keys:
            return True
        else:
            return False 

check_validity('A11')
```

Essentially the function above checks if the input is found in the list and returns true or false. This function is then called upon in the `prompting` function to see if the input is valid and to raise an error if it is not valid and therefore prompt the user to input a valid value. The issue I am having is that it will prompt the user to input but whether I put a correct or incorrect the value, the except block is always skipped. What should I/can I do to fix this.

If this is not possible when using a try-except block, then I would also like to know how I can fine tune an if-else statement to essentially do the same thing. I have experimented with this approach a bit but I am running into the issue of the error actually being raised but it won't prompt user input after (and I assume that is because it is not being looped by a while loop or anything like that. Thank you all who help.

Comment: You need to assign the return value of `check_availability` to a variable used in your if statement.

Comment: `except ValueError` in your current code won't ever be used, because the `input` function doesn't raise ValueErrors. It's a very generic function which has no knowledge of your rules about what is valid. If you wanted, you could call `check_validity` within the try block, and make `check_validity` raise a ValueError if it finds invalid input. However, personally I'd stick with having that function return True/False. In that case, you don't need try/except.

Comment: There's no need for the `for` loop in `check_validity()`. The whole function should be `return coordinate in coordinates_dict`

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback y'all, pretty much every bit of advice you all gave helped me figure it out one way or another. The `prompting()` function seems to be doing its job, the only issue is that when you are typing in invalid responses, if you do it enough times, it gets to a point where you may enter a valid coordinate and it won't register it and raise the `ValueError` but when you type in the second time it works. I am tweaking with it a bit to figure it out but if anyone has any idea then PLEASE LET ME KNOW! :)

Comment: Actually nevermind, I figured it out on my own. Once again, thank you all so much for your help.